# Can you use the Apple Watch Crown in apps?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, apple-watch

I'd like to use the crown for a special function in my Apple Watch. It seems like this isn't possible. Does anyone know if it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible at this time.